# Concept of ternary operator (? : ) in c

Tags: c, ternary-operator

On compiling  given program in **GCC Compiler** :

```
int main()  
{  
      int a=2,b=3;  
      (a>1)?b=10:b=50;  
      printf("%d",b);  
      return 0;     
}
```

it is showing error that **"lvalue required as left operand"**
 but if i write 4th line as 
     `(a>1)?b=10:(b=50);`
 Then its showing no compilation error . Can any one explain me why ? 
And also how does it differ from if...else...  ?

Comment: It's being parsed as: `((a>1)?b=10:b) = 50;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have an issue with operator precedence. Your code is interpreted as follows:

```
((a > 1) ? b = 10 : b) = 50;
```

The above code is invalid for the same reason that writing  `(b = 10) = 50` is invalid.

The code can be more clearly written as:

```
b = a > 1 ? 10 : 50;
```

> And also how does it differ from if...else... ?

The conditional operator works only with *expressions* as operands. An `if` statement can contain *statements* in the body.

A conditional operator can always be replaced by an equivalent `if` statement. But the reverse is not true - there are if statements that cannot be replaced with an equivalent conditional operator expression.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you encounter is operator precedence. The `=` operator has lower precedence than the `?:` operator.

Comment: Do you mean "The = operator has LOWER precedence than ?:". Because first the ?: is executed, then the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

I think your code should be:

```
int main()  
{  
      int a=2,b=3; 

      b=(a>1)?10:50; 

      printf("%d",b);  
      return 0;     
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: **b looks like a second-order pointer

Comment: Well sorry I didn't pay atention to other mistakes.
It should actually be as it is right now, and sorry for the **, I thought they would turn bold inner characters.